# How to do change color of the word for live template in pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

for example, I created such a live template.

```
{% for %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to change the color of the word "for".
how can I do it? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** This setting seems to be available for Professional version of PyCharm.

Go to `Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Django/Jinja2 Template > Tag Name`

[image: settings]

Comment: How to you downloaded this template? (Django/jinja2 template) I couldn't found. Please help me.

Comment: There's no template to download. Which version are you running?

Comment: I running 2019.1.3 version

Comment: I'm on 2019.2 but I doubt the feature is available after this version. Try searching for `Tag Name` using the search bar on top left

Comment: I downloaded and installed 2019.2 version. But there isn't (Django/Jinja2 template). Please help me



  https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBQHN.jpg

Comment: Did you disable any plugins?

Comment: I didn't. All plugins are enabled

Comment: Maybe try resetting PyCharm settings by renaming/deleting `c:\users\<username>\.PyCharm2019.2` folder to something else

Comment: I downloaded 2019.2 community version. that's why there wasn't (Django/jinja2 Template) but  I to day downloaded 2019.2 professional version. I found (Django/jinja2 Template). thank you so much

Comment: Ah, that difference completely flew over my head. Glad you could solve it.